# Как сделать чтобы скрипт применялся к одному id

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт параллакс эффекта при движении мыши. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы данный скрипт применить только к одной секции id (одному идентификатору) ??

```
let bg = document.querySelector('.mouse-parallax-bg');
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        let x = e.clientX / window.innerWidth;
        let y = e.clientY / window.innerHeight;  
        bg.style.transform = 'translate(-' + x * 20 + 'px, -' + y * 20 + 'px)';
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос понятен не до конца, но есть предположение, что Вам может подойти

1. `querySelectorAll('.mouse-parallax-bg')[i]`, где i - число, означающее позицию нужного Вам элемента.
2. `getElementById('id')` вместо `querySelector('.mouse-parallax-bg')`, но в таком случае у всех нужных элементов нужны id

UPD учитывая комментарий:
Тогда наверное можно взять по id сначала через `getElementById('id')`, а потом обратиться с поиском не к `document`, а к результату по id
Что-то вроде `document.getElementById('stages').querySelector('.mouse-parallax-bg')` должно получиться

Comment: Я имел ввиду, чтобы данный параллакс применялся к одной секции. То-есть section id="stages"

Comment: Обновил ответ с учетом Вашего коммента